How to keep the url of razor pages?
I am newbie.
I know I can set the url using UseUrls() to set the url of the website. or set it in IIS
now I want to publish one free website using razor pages but I want the user to only use the url of 'localhost' which means they only can use it on their own computer.
Users can get the source code but only can use localhost to run it.
I know razor pages cannot use native aot.

Hi, @liang.good!!! Just to be clear, you want to limit access to your website to only localhost, right? This will make the website accessible only from the local machine and inaccessible from the outside world.

Would you kindly share your existing code in order to investigate quickly. And explain a bit more what exactly you are trying to achieve, because, its not very clear what you are expecting.

@MdFaridUddinKiron, I have posted an answer below, based on my interpretation of the question (i.e., the OP wants to limit access only to localhost). Should this not be correct or off-topic, I will delete my answer.

So, you want to publish a "localhost" free version for users that is accessible only in their machine and when they pay, they can host it anywhere? Is this correct? If so, see this link for help: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/fundamentals/servers/kestrel/host-filtering?view=aspnetcore-8.0

Host filtering mechanism allows your website to respond to only "AllowedHosts" in the appsettings.json file.

If you want to limit access to your website to only localhost (127.0.0.1), you will have to use the UseUrls method In your Program.cs file as follows:
public class Program
{
    public static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        CreateWebHostBuilder(args).Build().Run();
    }

    public static IWebHostBuilder CreateWebHostBuilder(string[] args) =>
        WebHost.CreateDefaultBuilder(args)
            .UseUrls("http://localhost:5000") // Specify the localhost URL and port
            .UseStartup<Startup>();
}

Also, you will have to verify that this statement ("applicationUrl": "http://localhost:5000") is made on your launchSettings.json file, in case you are debugging with Visual Studio.

You can use custom middleware to limit access to your website like this :
 app.UseMiddleware() =>
        {
            return async (context, next) =>
            {
                if (context.Request.Host.Host != "localhost")
                {
                    context.Response.StatusCode = 403; // Forbidden
                    return;
                }

                await next.Invoke();
            };
        });

